# Syntax error: missing ';' before '*' when creating a pointer object of a user defined abstract class

Tags: pointers, directx, syntax-error, abstract-class

I am trying to create pointer objects for my defined class 'FeralScene'

But i keep getting this error "Syntax error: missing ';' before '*'"

i dont know wats wrong with my code... could smone pls help me out?

```
/***********************************************************************
2D Engine Header File

File Name:  FeralFramework
File Desc:  Header to the Main Framework file

************************************************************************/
#ifndef FERALFRAMEWORK_H
#define FERALFRAMEWORK_H

#pragma once
#include<Windows.h>
#include<d3d9.h>
#include<d3dx9.h>
#include<string>
#include <dinput.h>

#include"FeralScene.h"

#include"GraphicDevice.h"
#include "Stdinc.h"


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

class FeralFramework
{
public:
    LPDIRECTINPUT8 inputDevice;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Device;
    HWND WindowHandler;
    HINSTANCE Instance;
    FeralScene *CurrentScene,*PrevScene; // error occurs here

    GraphicDevice graphicDevice;

    static HWND StaticWindowHandle;
    static IDirect3DDevice9 *GraphDevice;

    int ScreenHeight;
    int ScreenWidth;
    bool IsFullScreen;

    bool WindowCreation();
    bool InitDirectx();

    void MessageLoop();
    void SetLighting();
    void UpdateDrawLoopCallFunction();
    void InitFrameWork();
    void Render();
    void initializeDirectInput();
    //void Camera(int mx, int my);

    void SceneSwitcher(FeralScene *SCENETOSWITCHTO);  
    // the FeralScene identifier error occurs here

    FeralFramework();
    FeralFramework(HINSTANCE Instance,int ScreenHeight,int ScreenWidth ,bool IsFullScreen,FeralScene *SentSceneObject );  
    // the FeralScene identifier error occurs here

    FeralFramework(HINSTANCE Instance,FeralScene *SentSceneObject);  
    // the FeralScene identifier error occurs here

};

inline LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND WindowHandler,UINT Msg,WPARAM wparam,LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return true;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(WindowHandler,Msg,wparam,lparam);
    }

}

#endif
```

And here is a list of the errors that pop up when i try to compile it

```
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(55): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FeralScene'
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(58): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FeralScene'
1>c:\users\sys\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\feralengine\feralengine\feralframework.h(59): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FeralScene'
```

What am i missing ? Any help will be appreciated :(

And here is the code for FeralScene

```
/***********************************************************************
2D Engine Header File

File Name:  FeralScene
File Desc:  Header to the FeralScene file

************************************************************************/

#pragma once

#include<d3dx9.h>
#pragma once
#include<Windows.h>
#include<d3d9.h>
#include<d3dx9.h>
#include"GraphicDevice.h"
#include "FeralFramework.h"
//#include "Vector.h"

class FeralScene
{
public:
    HWND WindowHandler;
    IDirect3DDevice9 *Device;
    int BackBufferHeight;
    int BackBufferWidth;
    bool IsFullScreen,HasLoadedResources,HasUnloadedResources;

    virtual void Initialize(FeralScene *SentSceneObject) =0;
    virtual void Load(GraphicDevice graphicDevice) =0;
    virtual void Update(GraphicDevice graphicDevice) =0;
    virtual void Draw(GraphicDevice graphicDevice) =0;
    virtual void Unload() =0;
    virtual void Lighting()=0;
    virtual void LoadAnim()=0;
    virtual void UnloadAnim()=0;
};
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code of FeralScene.h also.

Comment: added to my description bro ... :( any thoughts? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including FeralFrameWork.h in feralscene.h. Which doesnt know of FeralScene.h yet. You can crete a forward decleration in FeralFramework.h. Also I suggest using proper macros in FeralScene.h also to avoid multiple decelerations.

Since you are using pointer types in header forward decleration will resolve the issue.

```
   // this should be before the class FeralFramework
   class FeralScene;
```